# Is it really written "Bauer" here?

Tags: 19th-century, germany, palaeography, occupation, silesia

The profession of my ancestors is indicated in a catholic church book from Upper Silesia. I'm fairly confident they were farmers, so it should be written *Bauer* since the register is written in German.

However the word that is written doesn't quite look like Bauer. Is it really written *Bauer* here ? In the unlikely case where the word would be written in Polish, the other language of that country, it should read as *chłop*, however it doesn't look like that either. Here is several samples with different handwritings:

[image: handwriting sample 1]

[image: handwriting sample 2]

[image: handwriting sample 3]

Answer (score 4):

Using the same [BYU Script Tutorial](https://script.byu.edu/Pages/German/en/alphabet.aspx) as your other question, I have come to the conclusion the second image says *Häusler*, meaning simply "house owner" or "cottager". The same occupation is abbreviated *Hslr* in the first image.

According to this [List of Old German Professions](http://www.european-roots.com/german_prof.htm):

> The term for "house owner (with a little land for own use)" varies
> from region to region. The terms for the occupation mainly derives
> from the different word for cottage:
>
> cottager terms derived from Haus (house): Häusler, Heusler, Heißler,
> Hüssler, Auenhäusler, Tropfhäusler, Freihäusler;

The third image is more tricky. The bride appears to be recorded as  *Bauertochter*, meaning farmer's daughter. You will note a male further up the page as *Bauersohn* (farmer's son).

The best I can suggest for the groom is *Krämer*, a peddler or trader, although I am far from confident on this as it does not appear consistent with the other recorded occupations for this man.

Comment: Thanks. So basically, were they particular farmers living in full autarcy, eating what they produce instead of selling it like larger farmers does ? Or was it just common to name farmers like that in this particular region ?

Comment: @Bregalad I'll have to defer to someone who knows something about German genealogy. In England, a cottager was usually a tenant who (as you say) used his small amount of land to produce for his family, maybe sold a small amount at the markets, but often worked as a farm labourer as the primary source of income. I do not know whether this is the same meaning as Hausler.

Comment: The word **Bauernhof** means _farm_ in German.

Comment: The first two entries are from a birth record of the children, the last for the wedding record of the parents, the first line is dedicated to the husband and the second to the bribe although I am not sure if it appied for that particular column. (by the way I apologize for the bad picture quality)

Comment: I added a larger handwriting sample.

Comment: @Bregalad Thank you for adding the larger image. However, I've stared and stared at it cannot work out what the groom's occupation is. I've edited the answer to include a possibility, but I'm not confident in it.